# Hallar la letra que solo se repite una vez en una cadena de caracteres y mostrar su posicion?

Tags: c++, array, caracteres

El objetivo es ingresar el numero de caracteres que va a tener la cadena, y hallar la letra que solo se repite una vez `acum_menor`, luego mostrar su posición. Lo hice comparando la cadena con otra que contiene las letras del abecedario.

Pero al momento de mostrar la posicion en la que está la letra que no se repite no se me ocurre una manera de hacerlo, tengo que capturar la posicion de la letra cuya repeticion es menor a 2(osea 1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
int pos_letra= -1;
int main (){

  int lon;
cin>>lon;
 char* palabra = new char[lon];
cin>>palabra;

  int acum, acum_menor=2, i, menor, letra;

  char letras[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

  for( letra = 0 ; letras[letra] ; letra++){
    for( i = 0 , acum = 0 ; i < lon ; i++){
        if( palabra[i] == letras[letra] )
            acum++;
          if (acum==1 && pos_letra < 0)
            pos_letra=i;
    }
             if( acum != 0 ){
             cout << letras[letra] << " se repite " << acum << endl;
                if ( acum < acum_menor ){
                menor = letra;
                acum_menor = acum;
      }
    }
  }
  cout << endl<< letras[menor] << " es moss. se repite "  << acum_menor << " vez / en los " << lon << " participantes "<< endl;
  cout<<pos_letra<<" moss hallado";
  return 0;
}
```

- Ejemplo de entrada: `"xvxx"`.
- Ejemplo de salida:

  - `v se repite 1`.
  - `x se repite 3`.

Comment: ¿Qué errores te dan los bucles anidados?

Comment: en si funcionan bien , hacen lo que quiero. pero no se en que parte o como guarda la posicion de la letra que solo tiene una repeticion (ose donde acum es menor a acum_menor que vale 2)

Comment: No acabo de entenderte ¿Tiene o no tiene errores?. Creo que sería útil que pusieras un ejemplo de datos que proporcionas al programa y datos que el programa te devuelve al procesarlos.

Comment: acabo de editar el cogido, es mas especifico. gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu algoritmo es bastante ineficiente, por cada letra (exista o no exista en la cadena entrada) recorres la cadena entrada; de manera que acabas haciendo N×M operaciones. Se pueden reducir las operaciones con tan sólo recorrer la cadena de entrada.

#### Propuesta.

Yo empezaría creando un objeto para almacenar los datos que queremos tratar:

```
struct FrecuenciaLetra
{
    char letra = 0;
    int frecuencia = 0;
    int posicion = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
};
```

Este objeto nos dice, por cada letra, cuántas veces aparece en el texto y la posición en que fue encontrada por vez primera, lo siguiente sería crear una función que dado un texto, devolviese una colección de `FrecuenciaLetra` por cada letra diferente del texto:

```
std::vector<FrecuenciaLetra> reduce(const std::string &);
```

Como puedes ver, sigo el consejo de [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/178914/2742) en que se usa `std::string` en lugar de una formación<sup>1</sup> de caracteres. El algoritmo a seguir es sencillo:

```
FrecuenciaLetra items[std::numeric_limits<char>::max()]{};
int indice = 0;

for (int letra : palabra)
{
    auto &item = items[letra];
    item.letra = letra;
    ++item.frecuencia;
    item.posicion = std::min(item.posicion, indice);
    ++indice;
}
```

Creamos una formación de `FrecuenciaLetra` que contiene todos los caracteres posibles y utilizaremos el índice del carácter para acceder a la instancia de `FrecuenciaLetra` que corresponda. Una vez localizada la que corresponde aumentamos su frecuencia y nos quedamos con el índice más pequeño.

Como es probable que en la formación `items` encontremos posiciones vacías, filtraremos los resultados antes de devolverlos:

```
std::vector<FrecuenciaLetra> resultado;
std::copy_if(std::begin(items), std::end(items), std::back_inserter(resultado),
    [](auto &i) { return i.letra != 0; });
```

Con el código sugerido, probando con la cadena `"patata"`:

```
int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(std::cin, s);
    for (const auto &fl : reduce("patata"))
        std::cout << '\'' << fl.letra
                  << "' aparece por primera vez en " << fl.posicion
                  << " y aparece " << fl.frecuencia
                  << " veces en el texto.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Obtenemos la siguiente salida:

> ```
> 'a' aparece por primera vez en 1 y aparece 3 veces en el texto.
> 'p' aparece por primera vez en 0 y aparece 1 veces en el texto.
> 't' aparece por primera vez en 2 y aparece 2 veces en el texto.
> ```

Puedes ver el código funcionando <kbd>[Aquí](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1JKAS5JVrKRhletK)</kbd>.

---

1. También conocida como arreglo, o en inglés: array.

Comment: M e sorprende tu habilidad, pero me temo que esto nome es util :(, viene siendo programacion orientada a abjetos, y el objetivo de mi problema es practicar para un concurso de programacion estructurada. Sin embargo le voy a saxar provecho para futuros proyectos . Gracias! :)

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema tiene un nombre bien definido: **VLA** o **V**ariable **L**ength **A**rray

```
cin>>lon;
char palabra[lon];
```

`palabra` es un VLA ya que, aun siendo un array de tamaño fijo, el número de elementos se determina en tiempo de ejecución. Esta característica no está soportada por el estándar de C++... así que no la uses.

En su lugar opta por usar memoria dinámica:

```
char* palabra = new char[lon];
```

O, mejor aún, usa la clase `std::string` que para eso está:

```
std::string palabra;
std::cin >> palabra; // y esto funciona independientemente de la longitud de la cadena
```

Lo que hace que tu código no funcione correctamente se encuentra aquí:

```
int tam = sizeof palabra / sizeof palabra[0];
```

¿Y por qué esto es un problema?

Sencillamente porque `sizeof` se evalúa en **tiempo de compilación**... mientras que el tamaño de `palabra`, como hemos dicho antes, va a determinarse en **tiempo de ejecución**... el compilador no es adivino así que eso no va a funcionar en la vida.

Por otro lado... ¿Para qué tienes `tam` si ya has pedido la longitud en `lon`? A todas luces, `tam` sobra y, adicionalmente, si usas `std::string` también sobraría `lon`. Por ejemplo, para iterar en el rango `(0..longitud)` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
for( i = 0 , acum = 0 ; i < palabra.length(); i++){
```

Comment: tienes razon, ahora edito el codigo, pero aun asi tengo la duda de como ca[turar la pososicon de la letra que solo aparezca una vez :/

Comment: @GabrielBalderrama basta con que tengas una variable de tipo `int` a nivel del `main` (por ejemplo `int pos_letra= -1` y otra más dentro del primer bucle. La del primer bucle la actualizas con la posición de `i` cada vez que encuentres una letra. Luego, una vez recorrida la cadena, si `acum==1 && pos_letra < 0` actualizas `pos_letra` con el valor de `i` y listo.

Comment: @GabrielBalderrama Por cierto, si esta pregunta soluciona tu problema no olvides marcarla como solución (si no lo crees conveniente no hacen falta los votos positivos), si no la resuelve usa los comentarios para aclarar los problemas que te vayas encontrando (siempre centrados en la pregunta original). Así ayudas a futuros visitantes.

Comment: acabo de editar el codigo intentando lo que dices, pero da 0 todo el rato.  A lo mejor de otra forma?:/

Comment: @GabrielBalderrama lo que te está pasando es que o no has seguido los pasos que te he dicho o lo has hecho malamente... yo te recomendaría depurar el programa y analizar los motivos por los que no funciona como esperas... si aun así no consigues dar con el problema entonces plantéate poner una pregunta nueva